# facebook page access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to make aplication which get the posts of facebook page. I did everything and it is working fine but I have problem wih access token. I've tried some SO answers about making FB APP but it didn't worked for me. I got to point when my token expired then refreshed page but the page asked me to verify access. But I cannot have it like this, because it doesnt serve the purposse.

Now I'm taking the content from this url with file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/soecz/posts?access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAJrnTKwdTdaloBgShsNSIkJjspgQocumZB4CV4mZACpAo3xj57gYcVYYYeHDBxi2ltNCT7SZB0Yl51PBQCrInIKstadeRR5OidYG8pibAAUHIiC51QUxgfTgFMY4DLUlglda7YiaP5yQiYbRftxwipRK5MZBVyzags0eReHx");

But after 2 hrs the token expires and I got oath error. Do you ahve any solutions ? I will sue it to get the posts from page. I do not want to edit / post anything with this. Just get the posts and write them. Also I do not want to rediret users when the token expires. Thanks for solutions

Answer (score 0):

See scenario 5 of https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/. By extending the 2 hour (short lived) token for a 2 month (long lived) token you can query for the page token after which will not expire.

> Exchange the short-lived user access token for a long-lived access token using the endpoint and steps explained earlier. By using a long-lived user access token, querying the [User ID]/accounts endpoint will now provide page access tokens that do not expire for pages that a user manages. This will also apply when querying with a non-expiring user access token obtained through the deprecated offline_access permission.

So you will only need to "verify" once as a user then you can save the page access token after that.

Comment: I tried this 60 days token but when I put this token into my application I got also the comments, statuses of other users, etc. I want just posts from page.

Comment: @user217536 you didn't explain that in your question. That's how page posts work they include comments and statuses of fans. You will have to post filter the results in php.

Comment: The code above gets exactly only posts. AS you can see /soecz/posts?access_token this works exactly how I want but when I chabnge the token it doesnt

Comment: @user217536 could you pastebin the two different responses you get

Comment: Problem solved. I'm using API key which has no expiration and I managed to filter it. Thanks